# Comparison of two arrays regarding the text

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I've got two arrays which i want to compare. Therfore i want to check if they got equal elements regarding the `"text": ...`. If its equal it should return true, otherwise return false

```
  englishData = [
      {"data":"sandwich","text":"Sandwich"},
      {"data":"toast","text":"Cuisine"},
      {"data":"fries","text":"Pommes"},
      {"data":"salad","text":"Salad"},
      ]
  franceData = [
      {"data":"sandwich","text":"Sandwich"},
      {"data":"toast","text":"Kitchen"},
      {"data":"fries","text":"Pommes"}]
```

So far i tried it with a normal for-loop, like :

```
for (let i = 0; i < actualData; i++) {
   for (let j = 0; j < plannedData; j++) {
     if (actualData[i].text === plannedData[i].text) {
       return true
     } if (actualData[i].text != plannedData[j].text) {
       continue;
      } 
     }
       return false
  }
 }
```

Because of the different length, i wanted to compare each element in `franceData` with all elements in the original array `englishData`.
Its kinda woking, but im not sure if it's really the best solution regarding the performance, ... .

I also thought about some if statements, like:

```
  if(franceData.text.includes(englishData.text)){ return true }
```

Comment: What is the end game? what are you  trying to achieve? Can you please provide a context? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to find out common elements, you can try something like this

```
englishData = [
  { data: "sandwich", text: "Sandwich" },
  { data: "toast", text: "Cuisine" },
  { data: "fries", text: "Pommes" },
  { data: "salad", text: "Salad" },
];
franceData = [
  { data: "sandwich", text: "Sandwich" },
  { data: "toast", text: "Kitchen" },
  { data: "fries", text: "Pommes" },
];

var res = englishData.filter((ede) =>
  franceData.some((fde) => ede.text === fde.text)
);
console.log(res);

output:
[
  { data: 'sandwich', text: 'Sandwich' },
  { data: 'fries', text: 'Pommes' }
]
```

You can use map() in the place of filter to get just true or false for every match.

```
englishData = [
  { data: "sandwich", text: "Sandwich" },
  { data: "toast", text: "Cuisine" },
  { data: "fries", text: "Pommes" },
  { data: "salad", text: "Salad" },
];
franceData = [
  { data: "sandwich", text: "Sandwich" },
  { data: "toast", text: "Kitchen" },
  { data: "fries", text: "Pommes" },
];

var res = englishData.map((ede) =>
  franceData.some((fde) => ede.text === fde.text)
);
console.log(res.join("\n"));

output:
true
false
true
false
```